# Need help in html fluid/elastic/liquid layout. Please help me

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement fluid layout in my friend's site. But its not working. Its very simple page just a slider on it. Just take a look and tell me whats wrong with my code.

[Check the page here](http://girisoft.net/fluidlayout/)

Thanks

Comment: What's not working?  Could you show **some** of your HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.orbit-wrapper` and `#featured` have a fixed width in their style attributes. If you want it to be fluid, you'll need to do something using percent, possibly with a max and min width.